# mysql trigger insert minutely/hourly/daily average data when not exist; update for last minute/hour/day when exist (on duplicate key update)

Tags: mysql, triggers

To whom is willing to help:
Here is my purpose: I am now using python to scrap data from some servers and store data into mysql every 10 seconds, I will have 4 tables in the mysql, the origial table (s1_10s), 1 minute average (s1_1min), 1 hour average (s1_1hr) and 1 day average (s1_1day); all I need is that when a new line of data is inserted into table s1_10s, the other 3 tables need to be automatically updated. for example, for s1_1min table, if the inserted data has unique minute level, then insert a new line to it; if the inserted data has duplicate minute level, then take average of what is already have in s1_10s for the last minute.

I am thinking about using trigger, and on duplicate key update syntax, however, things always went wrong after many attempts. any suggestion will be appreciated.

```
insert into `s1_1min` 
select TIMESTAMP(DATE(datetime), SEC_TO_TIME(HOUR(datetime)*60*60+MINUTE(datetime)*60)) as datetime,
cast(avg(WS_mph) as decimal(6,3)) as WS_mph, 
cast(avg(WindDir) as decimal(6,0)) as WindDir, 
cast(avg(SlrkW) as decimal(6,3)) as SlrkW, 
cast(avg(SlrMJ_Tot) as decimal (6,6)) as SlrMJ_Tot, 
cast(sum(Rain_in_Tot) as decimal (6,6)) as Rain_in_Tot, 
cast(avg(AirTF) as decimal (6,2)) as AirTF, 
cast(avg(RH) as decimal (6,2)) as RH, 
cast(avg(Enc_RH) as decimal (6,2)) as Enc_RH,
cast(avg(BP_mbar) as decimal (12,3)) as BP_mbar
from `s1_10s`
where datetime>=DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)
group by TIMESTAMP(DATE(datetime), SEC_TO_TIME(HOUR(datetime)*60*60+MINUTE(datetime)*60))
order by TIMESTAMP(DATE(datetime), SEC_TO_TIME(HOUR(datetime)*60*60+MINUTE(datetime)*60))
on duplicate key update

WS_mph = avg(WS_mph),
WindDir =avg(WindDir),
SlrkW=avg(SlrkW),
SlrMJ_Tot=avg(SlrMJ_Tot),
Rain_in_Tot=sum(Rain_in_Tot),
AirTF=avg(AirTF),
RH=avg(RH),
Enc_RH=avg(Enc_RH),
BP_mbar=avg(BP_mbar)

group by TIMESTAMP(DATE(datetime), SEC_TO_TIME(HOUR(datetime)*60*60+MINUTE(datetime)*60))
order by TIMESTAMP(DATE(datetime), SEC_TO_TIME(HOUR(datetime)*60*60+MINUTE(datetime)*60))
```

Comment: Can you post your trigger code so we can see what issue might?

Comment: the trigger will be :create trigger insert_min
after insert on s1_10s